# Shall we use port 443 instead of tomcat default port 8443

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat9

By default tomcat use port 8443 and the same will update in tomcat default configuration files [server.xml,web.xml etc].

But in our requirement, I have to configure tomcat to use only port 443. Application is working as expected and I don't see any major errors with this change.

Do we have any security issues with this change?

Comment: It depends on how you run it. Privileged ports (< 1024) often require running as root. If you run your process as root, then if it's comprised it has much larger consequences.